# Was / Had been under the impression

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

I am writing about my childhood. Which tense should I use?

> I only played outdoor games. My friend once took me to his home and made me play the video game Mario.

> A.Before **I played Mario**, I **was** under the impression that all video games
> were violent.
>
> B.Before **I had played Mario**, I **had been** under the impression that
> all video games were violent.

> But this experience changed my thinking completely.

Comment: Both A and B are fine.

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends on the "voice" of your writing, which is a subjective, stylistic decision.  *In isolation*, either statement reads fine to me, and would be reasonably understood.

If you are already writing in the past tense, I would probably use the past-perfect tense in option B.  You *might* specifically use this form more in a third-person fictional account, to describe a past event that happened to a character that you were already speaking about in the past.

However, autobiographical writing tends to evoke a less-formal style, which might lend itself better to the conciseness of option A.

If this is an exam question, I'm not sure I'd get it right, even as a native speaker (albeit not an academic).  I am leaning towards option B, since the surrounding text is already in the past tense, while the choices describe an opinion held *before* the event of that surrounding text, and that is typically the distinction between how past and past-perfect is used.

The tag [past-vs-past-perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-vs-past-perfect), which was added by an editor, has many, many more examples.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, the most logical, or suitable ***usage/sequence of actions*** would be:

> Before I played the video game, I had been under the impression that
> all video games were violent. (The auxiliary in the independent clause, ...I had been
> [under]..., the past perfect is not necessary, it is rather advisory. So
> I have no problem saying: *...I was under...* );

However, your second example is not incorrect. But in this case, I would not try overemphasizing the perfect aspect. Conversational English tends to be more *colloquial and clear*. Therefore, I prefer the usage written above.